# Why Do I get this error when trying to create a bidimensional array with c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, parameters, return-value, max

First of all welcome and thanks for your help. I know that when you create an array with C++ the index must be a constant value, but I still get the same error, let me copy and paste the code so that you can understand what I'm saying:

```
const int four = 4, five=5 , six = 6, seven = 7, eight = 8, nine = 9, ten = 10, eleven = 11, twelve = 12, thirteen = 13, fourteen = 14;
```

This are my Constant numbers, right?, now take a look at this:

```
switch(random_number)
{
case 4:   GenerarMatrix(four,four);         break;
case 5:   GenerarMatrix(five,five);         break;
case 6:   GenerarMatrix(six,six);           break;
case 7:   GenerarMatrix(seven,seven);       break;
case 8:   GenerarMatrix(eight,eight);       break;
case 9:   GenerarMatrix(nine,nine);         break;
case 10:  GenerarMatrix(ten,ten);           break;
case 11:  GenerarMatrix(eleven,eleven);     break;
case 12:  GenerarMatrix(twelve,twelve);     break;
case 13:  GenerarMatrix(thirteen,thirteen); break;
case 14:  GenerarMatrix(fourteen,fourteen); break;
}
```

I'm calling the following function:

```
void GenerarMatrix( const int x, const int y)
{   
  int Matrix[x][y]; // Here I get an error, WHY if x and y are constant variables.

}
```

The error is expression must be a constant value

Comment: dimensions should be known at compile time

Comment: When you have an error it's helpful to include the exact error message in your question...

Comment: C++ doesn't have VLAs.  Use C if you want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It is not completely correct that the array dimensions must be a constant value. The compiler must know the dimensions of an array with automatic storage duration at *compile time*.

You are trying to create an array using a function that allows the dimensions to change during *run time*. You should use a container from the standard library to store your data instead.

Your function could just as well be used like this:

```
int i, j;
std::cin >> i; // Read value from standard input during program execution.
std::cin >> j;

GenerarMatrix(i, j);
```

And this is not allowed. That is why the compiler will give you an error.

A variable declared as `const` is not the same as it being available at compile time. It's perfectly ok to declare a `const` variable and initialize it with a value given at run time. For example:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i; // Value given at run time
const int j = i; // Ok to initialize constant variable with i.
```

---

You could define your function using `std::vector` instead:

```
void GenerarMatrix(const int x, const int y) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix(x, std::vector<int>(y, 0)); // Init to 0

    // ...
}
```

Now you can access elements in the same way as with an array, e.g. `Matrix[x][y]`, and it will work with dimensions given during *run time*.

**Also:** in the upcoming standard *C++14* a new container is introduced `std::dynarray`, which as `std::vector` can be allocated with a size given at runtime, but its size will be fixed at construction and will not change during its lifetime. This might be better suited for your needs if you know that the dimensions will not change. I don't know if any compiler supports it yet though.

Answer (score 0):

What are you really want from this peace of code?
(I don't understand, and looks like the compiler also)
You can create a variable for store bidimensional array with:

```
int[][] Matrix;
```

Or you can initalize a bidimensional array with:

```
new int[x][y];
```

or previous in one line:

```
int[][] Matrix = new int[x][y];
```

but

```
int Matrix[x][y]
```

is not correct declaration (i think)